# Map property whith where condition

Tags: c#, mapping, fluent-nhibernate

I have one table for 3 entities:
Password, Note, Credit Card.
The table has an "EntityType" column.
For example, for the password there is the value "P".
How do I make Mapping so that it takes only those rows where EntityType = 'P'

```
        public PasswordEntityMap()
        {
            Table(Constants.EntitiesTable);
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
            Map(x => x.Site);
            Map(x => x.Login);
            Map(x => x.Password);

            Map(x => x.EntityType);     <------- where EntityType = 'P'

            HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table(Constants.EntityAttachmentTable)
                .KeyColumn("EntityId");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a discriminator value for this.

```
public sealed class PasswordEntityMap : ClassMap<PasswordEntity>
{
    public PasswordEntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Site);
        Map(x => x.Login);
        Map(x => x.Password);

        Map(x => x.EntityType);

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("EntityType", "P")
            .AlwaysSelectWithValue();
    }
}
```

Then when you do a QueryOver for PasswordEntity only entities with "P" will be retrieved.

```
 var onlyPasswordEntities = _session.QueryOver<PasswordEntity>().List();
```